# How to avoid the spelling mistake of Android vs Andorid?

Tags: spelling, confusable, mnemonic

Most of the time when I'm trying to write the word **Android**, I get the confusion about it's spelling, like will it be **Andorid** or **Android**. So most of the time I was written wrong spelling.

To overcome this issue is there any tips or a way to remember the confusion between placing the And(**or/ro**)id?

---

<sup>Before posting here, I have confirmed in the [meta site](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3536/28470)</sup>

Comment: Learn to pronounce it. There's a [dr] sound not an [rid] sound.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo You should expand your comment and write an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Etymology may be of some use here:

**Android** comes from two roots: **Andr** meaning *man* and **-oid** meaning *shape* or *form of.*

The former appears in a few other words, such as

- **androgenous** - having neutral gender
- **polyandry** - having multiple husbands
- **misandry** - contempt for males
- **androgen** - a male hormone.

**-oid**  appears in many, many words:

- **Spheroid** - having the shape of a sphere
- **geoid** - having the shape of the earth.
- **haploid/diploid** referring to the number of unpaired chromosomes in a cell
- **humanoid** - similar in shape to a human.
- **steroid** - chemical compound with a shape similar to sterols (17-carbon 4-ring systems)
- **trapezoid** a quadrilateral having at least two parallel sides

To a native speaker, *android* and *andorid* sound very different, but I can imagine an accent that struggles with pronouncing and hearing "dr" as a single sound.   *Ezo* and *eoz* are a little farther apart, though.  If you can remember *trape**zoid*** (not *trap**eozi**d*) you can remember *andr**oi**d.*

Answer (score 2):

I can't see why you have such a problem as they are pretty different in pronunciation. There's a clear **[dr]** sound in **Android** and a **[dorid]** sound in **Andorid**.

If it helps just think of **Android** as of **"a droid"** but remember about the **[n]** sound, grammatically incorrect it would be **"an droid"**.

Answer (score -1):

This is easy!

I have heard a few calling 'Android' a 'Droid' phone. However, it is of Motorola. But then, it will help you remember the pronunciation and spelling!

Droids are from Motorola. So, 'dRoid' and not 'doRid'. There is no *...RID* - remember that way!

You are an Indian so think this way - it is एन ड्रोइड and NOT एन रोइड. The pronunciation is different and thus the spelling.

References:

https://www.motorola.com/us/compare-smartphones 
http://breon.com/android-and-droid-whats-the-difference/

---

Silly idea but may work!

If you use any document such as MS Word, it gives you an option to 'Autocorrect' the spelling. Go to the setting and replace 'Andorid' with 'Android!' Matter is over!